# Theme name passed into some of the functions?

Tags: theme-development

I use a theme called **vigilance**

I am starting to build my own themes and I notice in this them a lot of functions will have the theme name vigilance passed into the functions like this one below...

```
<?php _e( 'This post is password protected. Enter the password to view comments.', 'vigilance' ); ?>
```

Notice the theme name is passed as the second parameter, I am trying to figure out why?  I have not found anything supporting this in the docs yet?

Comment: Some useful links: [Function reference - _e](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) --- [What’s the difference between __(), _e(), _x(), and _ex()?](http://wpengineer.com/2237/whats-the-difference-between-__-_e-_x-and-_ex/) --- [What is _e, Exactly?](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/what-is-_e-exactly?replies=6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the [text domain](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Text_Domains), for use in [internationalization](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers).